Existence of a random variable $A$ with a given CDF, such that $A(x,0) = 1-A(x,1)$ on a standard Borel space
I have a standard Borel space $\boldsymbol{Z} = \boldsymbol{X}\times\boldsymbol{Y}$, where $\boldsymbol{X}$ is uncountable, and $\boldsymbol{Y}$ are measurable spaces with $|\boldsymbol{Y}|=2$, so we may as well say $\boldsymbol{Y}=\{0,1\}$. I also have a probability measure $Q$ on the standard Borel space $(\boldsymbol{Z}, \mathcal{F})$ (where $\mathcal{F}$ is some unspecified $\sigma$-algebra). I want to ensure the existence of a random variable $A:\boldsymbol{Z}\to[0,1]$ with a given CDF and the property that $A((x,0)) = 1 - A((x,1))$ for all $x\in\boldsymbol{X}$.
Here is what I have done so far:
Let $F$ be a function that is non-decreasing, right-continuous with $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$ (in particular $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x) = 0$). Such a function satisfies all properties of a CDF.
Since $\boldsymbol{Z}$ is standard Borel, I am pretty sure that $\boldsymbol{X}$ is also standard Borel (if not, I am willing to assume it is). A standard construction, of a random variable carried by the probability space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}[0,1], \text{Leb})$, where $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\text{Leb}$ is the Lebesgue measure is via the quantile function. Given a function that satisfies all properties of a CDF, such as $F$, the random variable $X$, defined by
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:QuantileRV}
    X(\omega) := \inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}:F(x)\geq\omega\}
\end{equation}
has $F$ as its CDF.
We can construct a probability measure $P$ on the measurable space $\boldsymbol{X}$ induced by $Q$, by projecting $Q$ onto $\boldsymbol{X}$. Define the projection map
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:ProjectionMap}
    \begin{aligned}
        \pi_{\boldsymbol{X}} : \boldsymbol{Z}&\to\boldsymbol{X}\\
        z = (x,y) &\mapsto x.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then $P := Q\circ\pi_{\boldsymbol{X}}^{-1}$ is a probability measure on $\boldsymbol{X}$.
Since $\boldsymbol{X}$ is an uncountable standard Borel space, it is in particular isomorphic to $[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Denote the isomorphism by $\varphi$. Then $X\circ\varphi : \boldsymbol{X}\to[0,1]$ is a random variable on $\boldsymbol{X}$. Now,
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:CDFTransfer}
    \begin{aligned}
        P\{x\in\boldsymbol{X} : X(\varphi(x)) \leq c\} 
        &= P\{\omega\in[0,1] : X(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(\omega)) \leq c\}\\
        &= P\{\omega\in[0,1] : X(\omega) \leq c\}\\
        &= F_X(c),
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
but we know that $F_X=F$, which shows that the random variable $B:=X\circ\varphi$ also has $F$ as its CDF.
Now we construct a random variable $A$ on $(\boldsymbol{Z}, \mathcal{F}, Q)$ by
\begin{equation}
        A(z) = A(x,y) := \begin{cases}
        1-B(x), &\text{if $y=0$}\\
        B(x), &\text{if $y=1$}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Since $B$ is measurable, so is $A$. It clearly satisfies $A((x,0)) = 1 - A((x,1))$. It remains to show that $F$ is the CDF of $A$.
It is clear that
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        F_{A}(c) 
        &= Q\{z\in \boldsymbol{Z} : A(z) \leq c\} \\
        &= Q\{(x, 0)\in \boldsymbol{Z} : 1-B(x) \leq c\} + Q\{(x, 1)\in \boldsymbol{Z} : B(x) \leq c\} \\
        &= Q\{(x, 0)\in \boldsymbol{Z} : B(x) \geq 1-c\} + Q\{(x, 1)\in \boldsymbol{Z} : B(x) \leq c\} 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
as the events are disjoint.
This is where I am stuck. I want the two terms to sum to $F(c)$, but I have no way of ensuring it that I am aware of. The measure $Q$ is given, so I have no freedom there, and if I want the symmetric property, it seems I have to construct $A$ the way I did. The only thing that remains open, is to restrict $F$ so that they sum up as desired, but I do not see how this can be done.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. What I am interested in is the existence of such a random variable, so if there is some way that avoids an explicit construction, that is also perfectly fine.

Not possible in general. E.g suppose that $Q(B\times{0})=Q(B\times{1})$ for all $B\subseteq X$. Then if the r.v. $A$ satisfies your condition $A(\cdot,0)=1-A(\cdot,1)$, its distribution must be symmetric around $\frac12$.

Thank you, @Wei, that makes sense. What I am after is to find conditions on $F$ so that there exists some random variable $A$ with the desired properties. I suppose that will depend on $Q$ then. Alternatively, can we find conditions on $Q$ so that it fits a given function $F$?
